# MySQL query with left join, count and group with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I have 3 tables where I am trying to put a join query like below.

The below is the Section table containing 3 sections.

```
Section
*****************************
* section_id * section_name *
*****************************
*  1         * A            *
*  2         * B            *
*  3         * C            *
*****************************
```

The below is the section_subject table.  1st section contains 2 subjects, 2nd section contains 2 subjects and 3rd section contains 3 subjects.

```
Section_Subject
***********************************
* ss_id * section_id * subject_id *
***********************************
* 1     * 1          * 8          *
* 2     * 1          * 9          *
* 3     * 2          * 6          *
* 4     * 2          * 5          *
* 5     * 3          * 2          *
* 6     * 3          * 3          *
* 7     * 3          * 4          *
***********************************
```

The below is the section_batch table.  3rd section alone contains 2 batches

```
Section_Batch
*********************************
* sb_id * section_id * batch_id *
*********************************
* 1     * 3          * 6        *
* 2     * 3          * 7        *
*********************************
```

I want a query to yield the below result

```
**************************************************************
* section_id * section_name * count_subjects * count_batches *
**************************************************************
* 1          * A            * 2              * 0             *
* 2          * B            * 2              * 0             *
* 3          * C            * 3              * 2             *
**************************************************************
```

I know that we can do some kind of sub query and achieve the above result.  But how to get the result using left join and group query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using `count(distinct)` will get you what you need. You have to use `distinct` because the joins have a multiplier effect where a section has more than one subject and more than one batch.

```
select
    s.section_id,
    min(t1.section_name) as section_name,
    count(distinct ss.subject_id) as subject_count,
    count(distinct sb.batch_id) as batch_count,
from
    Section as s
    left join Section_Subject as ss on ss.section_id = s.section_id
    left join Section_Batch as sb on sb.section_id = s.section_id
group by
    s.section_id
```

By the way, I think the left joins could probably be inner joins.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do `left join` and `group by` each table separately to get the count and then do a join between them

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4ee/12

```
select T1.section_id,
       T1.section_name,
       T1.subjects_count,
       T2.batch_count
FROM (
select S.section_id, 
       S.section_name,
       COUNT(SS.subject_id) as subjects_count
from Section S
LEFT JOIN Section_Subject SS
on S.section_id = SS.section_id
group by S.section_id, S.section_name )T1
LEFT JOIN (
select S.section_id, 
       S.section_name,
       COUNT(SB.batch_id ) as batch_count
from Section S
LEFT JOIN Section_Batch SB
on S.section_id = SB.section_id
group by S.section_id, S.section_name
  ) T2
 on T1.section_id = T2.section_id
```

Comment: Your solution works but I am not sure about the performance of this query since it executes multiple selects and group by.

Comment: @Malaiselvan You can test. This type of solution is often more efficient. Esepcially if you have more than 2 tables joined to the base table. Imagine there are 6 instead of 2. I'd bet on this type of 6 separate group by and then 6 joins than a huge 7-table join and then group by.

Comment: See my answer in a similar question at the sister site, dba.se: [Help with this query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count` with `distinct`:

```
select t1.section_id
     , t1.section_name
     , count(distinct t2.subject_id) as count_subjects
     , count(distinct t3.batch_id) as count_batches
from Section t1
left join Section_Subject t2 on t1.section_id = t2.section_id
left join Section_Batch t3 on t1.section_id = t3.section_id
group by t1.section_id
       , t1.section_name
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4ee/19)

Comment: @notulysees The count_subjects & count_batches for the 3 section shows 6 which is wrong.